# Cannot get message from the Azure Storage Account Queue in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, message-queue

I have a script where I dayly check if there are messages on the Azure Storage Account Queue. It was always working, but now not anymore. I dont receive errors. What is going wrong?

Here is my script:

```
 $queueUsername = "SomeGUID"
$queuePassword= "SomeGUID"
[securestring]$secStringQueuePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $queuePassword -AsPlainText -Force
$queueCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($queueUserName, $secStringQueuePassword)    
$message = $null
$queuemessage = $null
$resourceGroup = 'someResourceGroupName'
$storageAccountName = "someStorageAccountName"
$queueName = "someQueueName"
$accessKey = "someKey"

$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $accessKey
$queue = Get-AzStorageQueue -Context $storageContext -Name $queueName

$invisibleTimeout = [System.TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(10)
$queueMessage = $queue.CloudQueue.GetMessageAsync($invisibleTimeout,$null,$null)

if ($null -ne $queuemessage.result.asstring) {
    $message = $queueMessage.result.AsString
    $queue.CloudQueue.DeleteMessageAsync($queueMessage.Result.Id,$queueMessage.Result.popReceipt)
    Clear-AzContext -Force
    "Found item on the queue"
    $message | convertfrom-json
}
else {
    Clear-AzContext -Force
    "No item on the queue"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clicked on "Empty queue" and now it is working fine. It looks like there were some dequeue messages in the queue which were the problem.